# what has change in Java 7 for HashMap from Java 5

Tags: java, java-7, java-5

I'm not a java expert, just experience the change in the output of following program on Java 5 and Java 7. Could anyone has an idea what has change in Java 7 for HashMap implementation?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("1", "111");
        map.put("a", "aaa");
        map.put("A", "AAA");

        map.put("D", "DDD");
        map.put("d", "ddd");
        map.put("0", "000");

        map.put("B", "BBB");
        map.put("b", "bbb");
        map.put("2", "222");

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ "  "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output on Java 7

```
D  DDD
2  222
d  ddd
1  111
0  000
b  bbb
A  AAA
B  BBB
a  aaa
```

The Output on Java 5

```
0  000
1  111
a  aaa
A  AAA
B  BBB
b  bbb
2  222
D  DDD
d  ddd
```

Comment: Either the function `hashCode()` of `String` has changed or the internal Structure of `HashMap`. But what does it matter? You should never expect anything about the order of elements in a `HashMap`.

Comment: There have been several changes in implementation over time. You can see the [diff between Java 6 and Java 7](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=diff&id2=6-b14) for example (GrepCode doesn't maintain a copy of Java 5 source).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hashing algorithm changed. This means that you cannot rely on the iteration order of `java.util.HashMap`. This shouldn't come as a surprise, the JDK never gave any such guarantees in the first place. If order is important to you, use `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`.

JDK5 HashMap:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
   int h;
   return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

JDK7 HashMap:

```
final int hash(Object k) {
  int h = hashSeed;
  if (0 != h && k instanceof String) {
     return sun.misc.Hashing.stringHash32((String) k);
  }

  h ^= k.hashCode();
  // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
  // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
  // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
  h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
  return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Comment: And in Java 8 the hashing algorithm changed back to the Java 5 version again! A bit of history: The Java 7 algorithm was a fix for a vulnerability where an attacker could cause really bad performance of the `HashMap` by causing a lot of collisions. In Java 8 another fix was introduced, using search trees for bins with a lot of collisions.

Comment: That is excellent information. Thanks for sharing. I always wondered why they changed it in Java 7 and then back again in Java 8. If anyone is interested, the algorithm is the same in Java 9 (latest snapshot at the time of writing) as in Java 5 as well.

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` is an **unordered** Collection. As the Javadoc for [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) states

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you're looking for something that reflects any kind of order check out [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which will preserve insert-order.

The reason behind your changed order is most kikely the change in hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` does not maintain any order of the keys, so you shouldn't rely on such order. Last time I checked (Java 6 implementation), when iterating over the entries of a `HashMap`, the bins are visited in order (i.e. bin 0, followed by bin 1, etc ...) and in each bin the linked list of entries is traversed.

Without checking the Java 5 and Java 7 implementations, I can only say that the different order of iteration may be a result of either a change in `String`'s `hashCode`, a change in the way the hash code of a key is mapped to a bin of the `HashMap` or a change in the iteration order logic itself (I described that logic for Java 6).